# Presenting a specific view controller messes up the app on device (works on simulator)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, iphone-x

I'm facing a very weird bug. I have a button and I'm pushing a view controller normally, using segues. However, when I push the view controller the whole app layout messes up: it sometimes works, sometimes glitches such as leaving me with a blank view with nothing but the tabbar, or previous view controller still being seen but transformed to somewhere else in the screen etc. If I manage to go back, it *always* works fine after the first try. Here are some observations:

- Problem is specific to device (iPhone X). Simulator (even the same model and same OS version) works perfectly.
- Switching to modal doesn't matter. The "glitchy look" animates a bit different, but the problem is still there.
- Turning off animation in transition doesn't matter. It presents me a glitchy screen instantly, just without animation.
- Pushing/presenting the view controller from code (as opposed to storyboard segue) doesn't matter. Exactly same.
- Giving a delay (e.g. half second) after tapping the button before presenting the view controller doesn't change anything. Just wanted to try this to see if some race condition is present on tap, for whatever reason.
- The problem is specific to one view controller. Presenting anything else at the same segue/state doesn't cause any problem.
- The problematic view controller doesn't have anything special at all: It's actually just a wrapper with three child view controllers, something I commonly do:

[image]

- When I'm trying to present the problematic controller, I'm always getting this weird log:  `[Render] CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 1223558576 bytes`
- My application is definitely not out of memory. It's using ~50MB on iPhone X at the time of problem. It's a media app and can allocate ~500MB with no issues or crashes when shooting/filtering video etc.
- The problem occurs if a specific embedded view controller (the second one of three) is present. For example, if I remove the embed segue to that, it seems to run perfectly.
- That embedded view controller is a simple `UIViewController` subclass that just has a table view and some cells.

What might be going on?

Comment: My guess is the error message is misleading you. If you remove the 2nd embedded VC, you don't have problems... so... Look closer at what that VC is doing. Since it has a table view, and *"it always works fine after the first try"* - it sure sounds like something is not initialized properly the first time it's loaded. Put a few breakpoints in there, and see if you can narrow down ***exactly*** when it's failing.

Comment: where you able to solve this?, I'm facing a very similar issue

Comment: @JorgeAlfaro does the issue appear/disappear when you have that problematic view controller visible on app launch directly vs. it's offscreen initially?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I didn't test that scenario, I reworked some constraints, and changed my layout a bit and it now works as expected